# Outlets not working after showing "old" view again

Tags: objective-c, storyboard, iboutletcollection

I have several UIViews in my Storyboard and, of course, I can switch between them using a segue. Initially this works just fine:
notenKurse is a NSMutableArray, and kurse1Outlets is an outlet collection with my UITextFields.

```
int counter = 0;
for (UITextField *tf in kurse1Outlets) {
    NSMutableString *t = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [notenKurse objectAtIndex:counter]];
    NSLog(@"Object at index %i is %@", counter, [notenKurse objectAtIndex:counter]);
    if ([t isEqualToString:@"42"]) {
        [t setString:@""];
    }
    [tf setText:t];
    NSLog(@"UITextField in slot %i should now display %@", counter, t);
    counter++;
}
```

All of my UITextFields are displaying the value stored in the array. But if I go to another view (let's assume I have a Button for it ;) ) Change something, and then go back to the original UIView the above code still gets executed, and there are different values in the array (this is supposed to be). I can see that in the log. But the stupid UITextField just doesn't display anything. Neither what was in there before, nor the new text. But why? The log clearly shows that t is what it's supposed to be, so the error must be in writing it into the textfield, and therefore I guess it's an outlet issue...

Comment: if it helps: the code DOES set the right text, just to a totally different UITextField, one, which is not in my View. (I set the text and checked with tf.text. It does have the right text...

Comment: ok I think I found the problem: When I leave the view, and re-enter it again later, the outletcollection gets loaded again with the same values. Problem: The UITextFields are being generated again and they now are at a different memory address. So I'm setting the text of the old UITextFields which aren't displayed anymore. Any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no guarantee of the order of your outlet collection. It's treated very much like an NSDictionary as opposed to an NSArray - where order is guaranteed. Iterating over this sort of collection will yield different results for different devices/people/phase of the moon.

When I use a collection like this I tend to set the 'tag' and then reorder the outlet collection when viewDidLoad by sorting off of the tag.

```
self.calendarDayImageViews = [_calendarDayImageViews sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    if ([(UIView *)obj1 tag] < [(UIView *)obj2 tag]) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    else if([(UIView *)obj1 tag] > [(UIView *)obj2 tag]){
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    else{
        return NSOrderedSame;
    }
}];
```

Comment: I actually do that in the viewDidAppear method...
`NSComparator comp = ^(id a, id b) { if ([a tag] > [b tag]) { return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending; } if ([a tag] < [b tag]) { return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending; } return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame; };
 NSUserDefaults *prefes = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 self.kurse1Outlets = [self.kurse1Outlets sortedArrayUsingComparator:comp];`

Comment: Which code is run first. ViewDidAppear or your business logic in the lead post? Also, are you saying that you're setting the collection values UITextFields from external client code?

Comment: The viewDidAppear (an so the sorting) is called first. An no, I'm not, I tested saving the whole collection and reloading it again, but I already removed the code since it didn't work. Sorry for confusing.

Comment: Wow thanks, I went over it again to make sure it DOES get called first. Well it should've but due to a mistake of mine it didn't. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can just output the tf,by

NSLog(@"%@",tf);

To check if the tf is null

Comment: <UITextField: 0x822dd50; frame = (204 49; 44 31); text = '4'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; tag = 2; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x822f120>; layer = <CALayer: 0x822deb0>>

I guess that's not the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found it. I forgot to release some stuff, and so my UITextFields did get set before the array was sorted. My mistake!